# Hierarchy Tree in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

New to Python but slowly learning..

I have these 3 columns that i need to find a group together based on ID and ID_TO relationship.
However I do have like 100 IDs and 300 ID_TOs.. What is the best way to group these together using Pandas or any other packages..

```
File: 
ID  LEVEL   ID_TO
359144  1
509140  2   359144
524126  2   359144
500282  2   359144
608199  2   359144
670431  2   359144
684006  3   359144
652158  3   359144
671747  3   359144
674969  4   359144
332260  4   359144
333725  5   359144
```

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Set up the first data frame for Levels
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'Title': ['NMO', 'FMO', 'SGA', 'MGA', 'GA'],
     'Level': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'Sales Level': [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
    })
    
    # Bring over Report of Uplines
    df2 = pd.read_csv('query.csv')
    
    
    ##Merge the Levels to the Uplines
    df4 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='Title', right_on='TITLE', how='left')
    #df5 = df4.query('PID == 359144 or ID_TO == 359144')
    
    
    ##Sort Values and Print
    
    ##df4.to_csv ('Report.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Output:

```
359144
├── 509140
└── 524126
    ├── 500282
    │   └── 684006
    └── 333725
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  Can you show us an example of what output you expect?

Comment: @user3698018 - Please provide the expected output with an example. Also mention what are the conditions to get the required output.

Comment: Your exit does not match your entry. Please correct.

Comment: im trying to group them by level 1, 2, 3, etc

Comment: In your example, why does `684006` end up attached to `500282`? Couldn't it just as easily be attached to `333725`? What tells you which node is connect to which, past the first level?